# How do you take this limit algebraically (Not using the graphing calc)

Tags: calculus, limits, exponential-function

$$\lim_{x\to0}{\frac{e^x-1}{x}}$$

I determined the limit by graphing this and seeing that the graph approaches 1 as x approaches 0.   But, is there a way to algebraically determine this limit?

Comment: Are you familiar with L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: use $$e^x=\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Any calculation of this limit involves two things 1) defining what is $e$ and 2) defining what is $e^{x}$. The simplest approach seems to be defining $e^{x}$ as the inverse of function $\log x$ in the sense that $y = e^{x}$ if $x = \log y$ where $\log y = \int_{1}^{y}(1/t)\,dt$. Then this above limit is seen to derivative of $e^{x}$ at $x = 0$ and it easily evaluates to $1$. Another approach is using infinite series to define $e^{x}$ directly (as suggested in previous comment).

Comment: No, I'm not yet familiar with L'Hopital's rule.  Let me look that up now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No limit can really be computed by graphing; it's not difficult to present examples where $f(x)$ seems to be close to $1$ when $10^{-n-1}<x<10^{-n}$ (fix $n$ at will) but the limit is $0$. When I was a student, the questions about limits in Calculus exams for the students in Engineering were always of this kind, so they couldn't test with their pocket calculators.

Computing your limit depends on how you defined things. It's equivalent to determine the derivative of the exponential function $x\mapsto e^x$, because
$$
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{x+h}-e^x}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{x}e^{h}-e^x}{h}=
\lim_{h\to0}e^x\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}=
e^x\lim_{h\to0}\frac{e^{h}-1}{h}
$$

So, if you already know this derivative (you might, depending on how you defined the exponential function), you'd know the answer is $1$.

Otherwise, set $e^x-1=1/z$, so that $x=\log(1+1/z)$; when $x$ approaches $0$ from the right, $z$ approaches infinity, so your limit becomes
$$
\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{e^x-1}{x}=\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{1/z}{\log(1+1/z)}
$$
Let's compute the limit of the reciprocal:
$$
\lim_{z\to\infty}\frac{\log(1+1/z)}{1/z}=
\log\lim_{z\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{z}\right)^z=\log e=1
$$
Similarly you can compute the limit for $x\to0^-$. In conclusion, it depends on the tools you have available and no definitive answer can be given if you don't mention what these tools are.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

> $$ f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}. $$

Comment: The problem is that I am doing the original limit to prove the derivative of e^x in the first place.  So, I don't think I can take the derivative at zero to find the answer to the limit.